# react native firebase dynamic links package error

Tags: react-native

I am using @react-native-firebase/dynamic-links package
When clicking on the link which i created, it works fine for android but for ios it doesn't Redirect to my app and it gives me this screen in the browser

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an intermediate page and can be eliminated by configuring your dynamic links apple behavior like this. [image]

Comment: the problem is my app is installed but when using the link it doesn't redirect my to the app it's opening this tap in the browser

Comment: have u implemented deep linking? u also need to add the url scheme of deep link in xcode project